# Tapping Tags Loads Site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, ios-app

When tapping a [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) in the iOS app, it loads stackoverflow.com in the in-app browser, rather than going to the correct search in the app

[image] [image]

It seems, more broadly, there needs to be a generic hyperlink-to-app-section methodology to convert any arbitrary destination to the app's display of it.

Comment: On desktop, that link also takes you to the tag on the main site.  There are definitely spaces where we should be taking users to the in-app experience.  I don't know about the time-table.

Comment: ah, good point about the main site link. i didn't know of "meta-tag" formatting. will use that from now on

Comment: @BrianNickel, I have removed that section from this question, as I now see it is by design

Comment: It's on the list but a low priority right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in the area making user links work, so in the next build users, tags, and searches will all open in native views.